# MySQL install script

Tags: mysql

is there a way to automate to install MySQL without having to use the wizard to specify root password, etc.  Basically, I need to install MySQL as simple as possible for the end user.

Thanks

Comment: Which platform are you trying to install on?

Comment: This is probably a better question for serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you mean windows.  The Mysql MSI installer apparently has a quiet mode:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-installer-msi-quiet.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

It is really easy to manage mysql server through wampserver interface and it comes with phpmyadmin.

Comment: Wampserver installs php and apache too.  I don't think its the right answer if you just want mysql.